# Problem with custom routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, custom-routes

I'm using the following route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PatientList",
    "User/{SearchName}/{LocationID}/{Page}",
    new { controller = "User", action = "Index", SearchName = "", LocationID = 0, Page = 1 }
);
```

It fails on the following URL:  /user//1/1

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL `/user//1/1` is interpreted by ASP.NET as a request for `/user/1/1`. Only the last parameters can be optional. You can't skip a parameter this way.